# How to tell if JavaScript caused my update panel to update?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I use the following javascript code to call an update to my update panel after the page has loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoad(objSender, args) {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._doPostBack('updtPnlAccessoriesPanel', 'updtPnlAccessoriesPanel');
        }
</script>
```

I don't want the update panel (which has a user control in it) to fire until AFTER the page is loaded and is showing. This will allow it to update the update panel (and its user control) asynchronously.

So, in the user control's page_load, I want to tell it to ignore anything during the initial page load and only do its work when it is called by the javascript after the page has already loaded for the user. The work that is done in this user control takes several extra seconds and I don't want to it to slow the initial page loading down.

Any thoughts?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple - just use the `IsPostBack` to make your work after the page is loading, because when you trigger the UpdatePanel with your javascript you send a post back to the server. So do it like that:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        // now do your work
    }
}
```

To make it more advanced you can even simple check if the PostBack is from that panel. I use for that a function that check witch UpdatePanel is trigger the event, so the code we will be as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack && IsUpdatePanelInRendering(Page, upUpdatePanelId))
    {
        // run the code for update panel 1, me
        // ...
    }
}
```

where IsUpdatePanelInRendering :

```
public static bool IsUpdatePanelInRendering(Page page, UpdatePanel panel)
{
    Debug.Assert(HttpContext.Current != null, "Where are you called ? HttpContext.Current is null ");
    Debug.Assert(HttpContext.Current.Request != null, "Where are you called HttpContext.Current.Request is null ");

    // if not post back, let it render
    if (false == page.IsPostBack)
    { 
        return true; 
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            // or else check if need to be update
            ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(page);

            if (sm != null  && sm.IsInAsyncPostBack)
            {
                Debug.Assert(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form != null, "Why forms are null ?");

                string smFormValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[sm.UniqueID];

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(smFormValue))
                {
                    string[] uIDs = smFormValue.Split("|".ToCharArray());
                    if (uIDs.Length == 2)
                    {
                        if (!uIDs[0].Equals(panel.UniqueID, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            Debug.Fail("Ops, what we lost here ?");
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still cannot get it to behave correctly, Aristos.

I want the entire page to be rendered and visible including a few user controls, etc. Then, I want a particular update panel (which has only a user control in it) to load and do all its work after the other parts of the page are there. 

Also, the main page, in my case, does some work and saves a few bits of data in a session variable. I then want the delayed update panel/user control to use that to do some more work.

Comment: How can I tell my user control to not fire the first time the page loads and, instead, only do its work asynchronously via a javascript updatepanel call later on?